# Why does StackExchange itself login my OpenID account at StackExchange?

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

The [whois info of 198.252.206.71](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-198-252-206-0-1/pft) shows that it is an IP address from StackExchange, Inc.

It might not be a big deal the service provider itself can access your account, but an unknown IP address appears on the [login history](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) is a pretty scary matter to be seen.

[image: login history screenshot]

Comment: ... maybe this is an auto-login to a site? Not sure.

Comment: See related answer by the dev here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314298/399844